# How to destroy swipe.js completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using [swipe.js](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe) in a project.

I am dynamically changing the data in the slider.

I have been just creating a new swipe object when the data changes, however it is not destroying the callbacks etc, which is causing problems. How can I destroy the swipe object, or at least refresh it?

```
    <div id='flyers'>
      <ul>
       <li style='display:block'></li>
       <li style='display:none'></li>
       <li style='display:none'></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  window.slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('flyers'), {
    startSlide: 0,
    speed: 200,
    callback: function(event, index, elem) {
        $('#home .flyerNav .selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('#home .flyerNav').children().eq(index).addClass('selected');
        $('#home .flyerLoves').attr('imgId',slides[index].imgId);
        daterizer(index);
    }
  });
```

Comment: i have tried window.slider = null;  i honestly have no idea how to do it haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [swipe2 branch](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/tree/swipe2). It has a `kill` method that will remove the event listeners it sets up. I'm assuming it's not officially "done" yet but it might work for you if it doesn't have any glaring bugs. You'd call `window.slider.kill()` just before you instantiate the new one.

Comment: The current master branch now has the kill method exposed as the public api. You should now be able to call `yourSlider.kill()` using the current release. The docs have not been updated yet.